# Task Workflow to send email to Who (Lead or Contact)

Tags: workflow, tasks, email-alert

I have a situation where I want a certain type of Task to trigger an email alert to the "Who" Contact or Lead that the task is related to. In the Spring '16 release Salesforce added the ability to send Email Alerts on Task workflows, which is great, but I can't seem to make it send to the related Lead or Contact - they don't come up as options for the Recipient.

Has anyone found a workaround to this?

Comment: And Related Contact or Lead Owner which is a choice in the recipient drop down doesn't work?

Comment: No - I don't want to send email to the related Lead or Contact Owner, but to the related Lead or Contact themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Create a custom Activity field `Email__c` of type Email
2. Populate it with the trigger below
3. You now have an email field available to the Email Alert

   ```
   trigger TaskTrigger on Task (before insert, before update) {
     set<ID> lIdSet = new set<ID>();
     set<ID> cIdSet = new set<ID>();
     for (Task t : Trigger.new)  // collect parentIds
        if (t.whoId == null) {}
        else
        if (t.whoId.getSobjectType() == Lead.SObjectType)
           lIdSet.add(t.whoId);
        else
        if (t.whoId.getSobjectType() == Contact.SObjectType)
           cIdSet.add(t.whoId);

     // Find the parents
     map<ID,Lead> lIdToLeadMap = new map<ID,Lead>([select id, email 
                                                       from Lead where id IN :lIdSet]);
     map<ID,Contact> cIdToContactMap = new map<ID,Contact>([select id, email 
                                                       from Contact where id IN :cIdSet]);

     // now populate the custom email__c field from parent
     for (Task t: Trigger.new) 
       t.email__c = lIdToLeadMap.containsKey(t.whoId)
          ? lIdToLeadMap.get(t.whoId).email
          : cIdToContactMap.containsKey(t.whoId)
              ? cIdToContactMap.get(t.whoId).email
              : null; 

     // since this is a before trigger, changing value of Trigger.new members implicitly updates the database
   }
   ```

Comment: Brilliant, I will try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for the great advice and working code!